# GCS bucket migration across different organisations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We are currently planning to migrate some GCS buckets across different organisations.

After having a look at the documentation, it seems that that's something one can do between projects and buckets, but not between different organisations.

Does anyone know if that is the case or is there any other way of migrating as part of the GCP toolset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS long as your IAM (identity) has a rule and policy associated with the source and target bucket's in different organizational units, you can seamlessly run `gsutil cp` to copy content across locations or organizations.

Essentially, you are looking at bare minimum roles i.e. `roles/storage.objectViewer and roles/storage.objectCreator`    for the user who will run this copy command